# Método isMember en mensajería electrónica. ¿Cómo comparar cada id?

Tags: java, poo, herencia

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de mensajería electrónica con diferentes clases y aplicando herencia.

Quisiera saber como resolver el siguiente método: `isMember(...)`: se le pasa por parámetro un identificador de contacto(ya lo tengo hecho en la clase principal con un método llamado getId) y devuelve verdadero si está contenido en el grupo (directa, o indirectamente), y falso, si no se encuentra.

Mi principal problema es no saber como comparar cada id con los que componen un grupo(clase sobre la que estoy trabajando).

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes el grupo de contactos en un `ArrayList` seria:

```
return grupo.contains(contacto.getId());
```

Si fuera algún tipo de colección que no tenga un metodo parecido, puedes iterar buscando el valor así:

```
String idBuscado = contacto.getId();
for(Contacto c : lista){
    if(c.compareTo(idBuscado) == 0)
        return true
}
return false;
```